# Assign an object to a let keyword when outside of scope

Tags: javascript, scope, mocha.js, let

At the moment, I am using a `var` that is assigned an object from another `hook`. I am wanting to change this to a `let`, but I keep stumbling across errors.

Current setup:

```
var tc;

module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    tc = new func()(x, y); // needs to be assigned here.
  },

  'Test': function (browser) {
    tc // needs to be referenced here too.
  },

};
```

How can I change it to `let` yet assign/reference it within other hooks and test cases (I'm using Mocha).

Answer (score 0):

Use *this.parameter*

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    this.tc = new func()(x, y); // Now it's assigned to the object context.
  },

  'Test': function (browser) {
    return this.tc; // You can reference to the variable inside the object
  },

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I reference a parameter inside the `tc` object within the `test` function?

Comment: Do you say something like this?
`test: function() {
     return this.tc.param;
}`

Comment: Kind of. Within the 'test', I would like to pass a parameter from the `tc` object to another function. Like so: `browser.page.function(tc.parameter, tc.anotherParameter);`

Comment: `browser.page.function(this.tc.parameter, this.tc.anotherParameter);`, like this?